# Loop for each message in mail file

Tags: bash, postfix-mta

My mails are stored in /var/mail/ file.

I want to write a bash script which will loopfor  each message.
I do not know how to split messages from a file.

Thanks

Comment: Is this a learning exercise? Why take this approach?

Comment: because the file is so big that popa3d gives me an error

Comment: There is no clarity on how the user wants to split the files

Comment: i want to extract messages one by one

Comment: The format specification you're looking for is [`mbox`'s](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4155). The format isn't trivial, so I advise to use an existing parser. You should probably research how to fix the error encountered by `pop3ad` rather than rolling your own parser.

Comment: `man formail`... In particular, `formail -s`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit : typical case of "When all you have is an hammer, everything looks like a nail" ; check `formail` from the procmail mail-processing-package as suggested by [twalberg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1253222/).

For something quick and dirty, you should be able to use the following to separate the records with NUL bytes which would make iterating over them easier :

```
sed '/^\n/N;s/^From/\x0&/' /var/mail/targetMailbox
```

For example you can use this command and `split` to split your mailbox into multiple files of manageable size :

```
sed '/^\n/N;s/^From/\x0&/' /var/mail/targetMailbox | split -l 100 -t'\0' - /tmp/mailbox
```

This command will split the mailbox into chunks of 100 messages which will be written to their own file in `/tmp/` ; check `split`'s options if you're interested in splitting the file, it supports a lot of different ways to do so.

A lot of (recent?) GNU tools will have a `-0` or `-z` option to make them handle `NUL`-separated records, for example :

- `-z` for `grep`, `head` and `tail`
- `-0` for `xargs`

To iterate over them directly from `bash`, the easiest is to use a `while read` loop with `read`'s `-d` option to specify the use of NUL as a separator.

For a more permanent solution, you need to find how to use an existing `mbox` parser.

Comment: I think this would fail for some mail, a linefeed followed by `From` in the body of the mail would be considered as a separation between two mails. While this could be avoided (Headers will end in EOL, while I don't think you could find EOLs in the mail's body), using a full-fledged parser is probably the best solution to this kind of corner-cases, of which I'm surely missing a few.